# F# Newbie: Why does this function return array?

Tags: arrays, f#

From what I've read, a function in F# returns the value which is the last line in that function. So how does the following function return an array?

```
let swap (a: _[]) x y = 
    let tmp = a.[x]
    a.[x] <- a.[y]
    a.[y] <- tmp
```

Comment: Wrong question, can't delete.

Answer (score 2):

The function you've posted does not in fact return an array, it returns a `unit`. This is because the type of the last line is `unit`, by design of the `<-` operator.

The function you've posted is not a pure function because it has side-effects. The swap occurs on the array by reference, because .NET arrays are mutable and reference types. A more "pure" swap function would produce a new array without modifying the input array.